# Is there any point to using a variable as a function parameter?

Tags: functions, argument-patterns

Normally one only sees patterns as function parameters:

```
fun1[x_]:=x^2
```

Is there any point to using a variable in a function definition:

```
fun2[y]:=x^2
```

I suppose to make this work I have to define *y* as a pattern:

```
y=x_
```

Is there any useful application where this occurs?

Comment: `fun2` will only give a result for argument `y`, and will remain unevaluated otherwise. The point of using a pattern is that it's a "dummy" (satisfying the appropriate conditions) that can be replaced.

Comment: @J.M. I know why patterns are used. I am asking if there is an application for using a non-pattern parameter.

Comment: To make the first sentence in my previous comment more explicit: it can happen that you want your function to evaluate only for *literal* arguments. Special cases, or what have you.

Comment: You can use a variable in a function definition as an index. [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html#10970) is a Wolfram Language Tutorial example.